# How to generate SQL statement with LIMIT clause but without OFFSET clause in jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to use jOOQ to generate the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM students
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

To generate the above statement with jOOQ:

```
String sql = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES).select(
  field("id"),
  field("name"))
  .from("students")
  .orderBy(field("id").desc())
  .limit(inline(50))
  .getSQL();
```

But I get the following:

```
select id, name from students order by id desc limit 50 offset ?
```

How do I remove the `OFFSET` clause? I know that I can specify the offset value to 0, which is same as omitting the `OFFSET` clause, but I want to know whether I can completely remove it from the generated SQL statement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, jOOQ 3.4.2 currently renders an `OFFSET` clause for PostgreSQL, regardless of whether it was specified by users through the API or not. That could probably be improved. I've created issue [#3577](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3577) for this.

Currently, there isn't really an "easy" way to change the generated SQL in this case. You could be implementing an [`ExecuteListener`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html), and patch the generated SQL - but you'd also have to get rid of the bind value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will assign `0` to the OFFSET value for the moment.

Comment: @Alex: Yes. By using `inline(0)`, you can also avoid the unnecessary bind value, in this case.